# Rendering inline HTML from Play Framework using Scala?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.1

How do I render inline HTML from Play 2, without using an external template file?

```
def checkStatus = Action {
  val status = ...
  if (status.ok) {
    Ok("Status OK")
  } else {
    // Oops, this renders the literal text instead of the HTML I wanted:

    Ok("Bad status, check out <a href='http://help.us.com/'>our help page</a>")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Ok("Hello World!")` sets the `Content-Type` header to `text/plain` unless explicitly specified:

```
Ok("Bad status, check out <a href='http://help.us.com/'>our help page</a>").as(HTML)
```

[Docs](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaResults)

Answer (score 2):

When you are rendering the view, Play recognizes its type (at least for html, xml, and txt), but when you want to return common `String` you need to instruct which type it is (otherwise it's assumed as `text/plain`)

According to [Manipaliting response doc](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaResults) you need to return with with the type:

```
 BadRequest("Bad status, check out <a href='http://help.us.com/'>our help page</a>").as("text/html")
```